# Navigation bar for online bus pass system

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to make Navigation bar for Online bus Pass management System

requirements

Navigation
1.Homepage
2.New Pass
2.1Generate pass
2.2Update pass
3.About Us
4.Information
5.Support forums

Accounts
1.Register
2.Login

please help me for make that code in html,css and js.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to create a nav bar, but your question is asking for a single answer and there is no single answer. My advice would be to look up a youtube video "Nav Bar Css". A video will help you understand css, html, javascript, and teach you how to create a nav bar better than words written in a post will.